# Transformation of regression model to estimate sum of coefficients

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

How can the model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+e$ be transformed so that it estimates the sum of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, that is, $\beta_1+\beta_2$ is a coefficient in the new model?

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have an example when this could be relevant, or is it just a theoretical problem?

Comment: This is simply a theoretical problem. One which arises from a question in an econometrics textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new model should be $y=\beta_0+\left(\beta_1+\beta_2\right)x_1+\beta_2\left(x_2-x_1\right)+e$.